# 60 amp detached shop able to run 50 amp hot tub?

Tags: circuit-breaker, pool, hot-tub

my house main panel is 200 amp, the shops panel is 60 amp. My new tub is closest to my shop but wasn't sure it would cause my shop to trip with the tub on its 50 amp gfci circuit? I was going to run from my house 200 amp but the teck AWG #6 is going to be very expensive to run that distance hence me researching if it's safe and able to be done through my shops 60 amp service. I've read it's safe and fine as most tubs that require 50 Amp fuse usually run at a 40 amp level. I'm just concerned it would trip the 60 Amp shop breaker, I don't run much in my shop other then lights and tunes and the odd power tool and my welder but figured I can just turn the tub off durang that. Any input would be great.

Cheers
Danny

Comment: I remember reading very similar questions, a few times on the site. Searching for duplicates...

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine if you install a 50 amp breaker into a 60 amp panel. Just shut the breaker off before using your welder.(Depending on its size it could draw quite a bit.)

The breaker should be sized by the manufacturer at about 125% of the tub's actual load. So like you say it may draw 40 amps at times when the heater is going full bore. When the heater is off it will draw much less than that.

The worst that can happen is you might trip the main in the shop if you forget to turn off the tub.

The only other thing of concern is voltage drop on a large load. Check the voltage at your shop panel while you have a large load on it to see if the hot tub would be undervoltaged or give us the particulars and we can help you calculate the voltage drop.

Happy Monday!

Comment: Excellent and thankyou for the good info. Once I'm wired and ran it for awhile I'll post an update on how it did.